# mongoose.connect - Doesn't fire callback (mlab)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, networking, windows-10, mlab

Starting a couple of days ago, I started having an issue connecting to my mlab hosted MongoDB instance. There have been no code changes and it still works on my other laptop as well as my teammates computer. The below code produces no output - I assume this means the request is getting lost somewhere. Any suggested steps to debug this would be much appreciated!

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@ds123456.mlab.com:12345/dbname', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("Failed to connect to database");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Successfully connected to database");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out that I was using Mongoose version **3.8.0**. Updating Mongoose resolved the issue.

Still not sure why it only broke on this computer but maybe this solution will help someone!

Comment: What happens if you do this `if(err){console.log(err);}`

Comment: "Failed to connect to database" never fires so this wouldn't fire either.

Comment: Is that the output while you console the error message directly ? `console.log(err)` ?

Comment: Hi Michael Auger; if you have found a solution to your problem, then the best thing to do is to post that as an Answer below; then you can [Accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your answer, and your question will no longer show up on the _unanswered_ list.

Comment: Sulthan - The problem is that the callback is never invoked so there's nothing that can be logged.

Comment: Vince - I was told that I should not put it there so I deleted it, I will add it back :). Possibly there is a better answer to this question though? Since the question itself asks for steps to debug this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was using Mongoose **version 3.8.0**. Updating Mongoose resolved the issue.

Still not sure why it only broke on this computer but maybe this solution will help someone!

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, please do the edits in your question itself